# When deploying to my server, the images folder routes dont work

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

So ill try to explain a bit better here, when i upload some files to my localhost and i retrieve them everything works fine, but in my server it doesnt work, im using a react node express postgress app with graphql and apollo, also prisma, soo when i run the npm run build and i run it it breaks, the route changed and i have no clue on how to fix this.

So i have uplaods which is where the images go

```
└── src
    └── uploads
    └── components
        └── files
```

I have an idea on where to find my files buuut i dont know how to access them

Comment: How you are trying to retrieve the images? As an <img>? Importing the file? I think that this can help you: https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/static-assets.html

Comment: im uploading files and showing them thats the problem, static files work fine